# What is the command to show the content of tablespace?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dll

What is the command to show the content of tablespace?

Oracle, dll

Comment: What content are you trying to display?  Information about what segments reside in the tablespace?  The data in those segments?  Something else?

Comment: What about the "main tablespace" are you trying to display?

Comment: let's assume it's called "tablespace" and I'd like a command to show its all contents

Comment: information about what segments reside in the tablespace, not data

Comment: What contents are you trying to show?  Are you trying to show, for example, the name of all the segments in the tablespace?  The name of the objects those segments correspond to?  Are you trying to see what data files are used by the tablespace?  How much space is used?  How much space is free?  Are you trying to query the actual contents of the table(s) that have data in the tablespace?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the segments that reside in the tablespace

```
SELECT owner, 
       segment_name,
       partition_name,
       segment_type,
       bytes
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE tablespace_name = 'NAME_OF_TABLESPACE'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME "TABLESPACE",
   INITIAL_EXTENT "INITIAL_EXT",
   NEXT_EXTENT "NEXT_EXT",
   MIN_EXTENTS "MIN_EXT",
   MAX_EXTENTS "MAX_EXT",
   PCT_INCREASE
   FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;
```

If you want to know about fee space, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME "TABLESPACE", FILE_ID,
   COUNT(*)    "PIECES",
   MAX(blocks) "MAXIMUM",
   MIN(blocks) "MINIMUM",
   AVG(blocks) "AVERAGE",
   SUM(blocks) "TOTAL"
   FROM DBA_FREE_SPACE
GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_ID;
```

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces014.htm#ADMIN11410)